# A word that means "how well it is written"?

Tags: word-request

A word that means "how well it is written"?

I am trying to think of a word that means that, but the closest thing I can think of is "form", which doesn't mean the same thing.

Example:

> This author doesn't write good novels, because he focuses on the form
> instead of the plot.

I am trying to find a word that means the state of being well written, but as I said I can't think of any other word that form.

Comment: poetic quality? poetic language? lyrical quality?

Comment: HIs books are not well written. plot is a kind of form....

Comment: I don't think there is one word for this. Perhaps just reword it: he focuses on **his writing** instead of the plot, or perhaps **his writing skills**

Answer (score 1):

The term would just be “well-written”, which is defined as:

> written in an effective or interesting way

Unless you mean something else?

Comment: And as a noun, simply "his writing". I think _He focuses on his writing rather than the plot_ conveys exactly what you want.